# rotate without losing speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

i have a tank that is rotating toward the middlepoint of the camera i use a slerp. but it is slowing down if it almost there.

```
        private void RotateHull()
        {
            Quaternion target = Quaternion.Euler(0, _mainCamera.transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
            hull.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(hull.transform.rotation, target, Time.deltaTime * turnTime);
            //SetRotate(hull, _mainCamera);
        }
```

this is the code. hull is the koepel en gunner.

Comment: The code is correct and it is doing what you tell it to do. The question is incomplete if you do not specify what you expected this code to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `Lerp` (or Slerp for that matter) is inappropriate here.

What you should use is [Quaternion.RotateTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html), since that will allow you to rotate at a constant pace.

```csharp
private void RotateHull()
{
    Quaternion target = Quaternion.Euler(0, _mainCamera.transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
    hull.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(hull.transform.rotation, target, Time.deltaTime * turnTime);
}
```

Comment: if i use that nothing happens anymore

Comment: @BenjaminVenema what is the value of your `turnTime`?

Comment: yeah it was way to low tank you <3

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are getting is a "smooth" behavior because you literally programmed it in that way. Also, the third parameter `t` is a percentage from `0f` to `1f` as you can se [from the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html), so I really don't know how `Time.deltaTime` will affect the behaviour, but it is probably unwanted.

Consider `a` and `b` to be quaternions. If you do something like `a = Slerp(a, b, 0.1)` you will move it 10% until `a` reach close enough `b`. So you are moving just a part of the way, and it will become slower at end.

As in the time of this answer you did not specify what you want the code to do, you have three options:

1. If you want a linear behavior, you should iterate the third parameter `t` from 0 to 1 in a given time. That will get rid of the smooth behavior. You can use a control variable or a Coroutine for that.
2. You can increase the third `t` parameter to a fixed percentage (say `0.2f`), removing deltaTime, and use some trial and error to get a satisfatory result.
3. You can implement an "ease out" behaviour by increasing the value of the third parameter `t` over time, just remember to reset it when you start a new rotation.